# Как сбросить биты с четными смещениями?

Tags: ассемблер

Присвоить ЕАХ значение 0FFFFh. Показать ЕАХ.
Сбросить в нем все биты с чётными смещениями. Показать за экране консоли результат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать [битовую маску](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0):

```
and eax, 0AAAAAAAAh  ; 10101010101010101010101010101010b
```

[image: Пример побитового И]